How to negotiate such toxic competitiveness during my master’s studies?
I came to a university for my master's studies in computer science, along with five batchmates from my country. Since most groups are formed in threes, two teamed up with me and instructed me not to help the other two. While strictly against plagiarism, I see nothing wrong with collaborating and sharing information.
I soon noticed that these two group mates only care about people they deem helpful and ignore entirely those they consider beneath them. You also lie to mislead others and ensure they don't complete assignments correctly. For example, one of them lied about finishing an assignment, saying he hadn't completed it when he had. e could have said, "I've completed it but can't share it. However, I can help you understand the topic." This behaviour annoyed me, and I began distancing myself from them.
Realizing this, they flattered the other two batchmates and included them in their team, trying to isolate me further. Unfortunately, I later discovered that the other two shared their mindset of ignoring those they don't need. I am without teammates and handling everything alone, which puts much pressure on me.
There was an internship position for five people, which they secured by approaching the professor before I could, despite my better grades. I was preoccupied with completing my courses alone. There was one more position available, but they didn't inform me.
When I finished my exams and sought a position, only a lesser opportunity was left, offering one-third of their total payment. I found out I would be working in the same lab as them. On the first day, their pale faces showed they didn't want me there. Hey had not told me about the opportunity they secured a month earlier, yet they questioned why I hadn't informed them I was joining the lab.
These childish, competitive antics are making me feel sick. Sometimes, I wonder if I did something wrong. I grew up in a different culture, where I competed with myself rather than engage in such competition with others. Unfortunately, I now have to work with the same team. I'm worried they will plot against me to force me out.
Please advise on how to address this situation.
Clarification based on a few answers:

I have no complaints about not being informed initially. I focused on my exams and approached for the internship two days before the deadline, getting a smaller package. When I didn't inform them about my role, they reacted negatively, though they hadn't informed me either.   Later, I discovered the professor was looking for one more person, and the slot remained empty. It made me feel they might not want me on their team. Should I be comfortable with working in the same lab going forward?

Initially, I chose to work with them due to the ease of language. However, they isolated one of our four apartment mates, ignoring his general questions and confusing us about course topics. When I asked why, they said he was from a lower-ranked faculty (business) and wouldn't be helpful to them in the future. His behaviour disgusted me and seemed likely to spread unnecessary toxicity. Helping: I mean answering general questions or helping resolve confusion regarding a topic, not explicitly tutoring him. Would someone have to lie because he is from a lower-demand faculty?

After the incident mentioned in point 1, I worked with other people, including those from different countries. Any of them were warm, collaborative, and helpful with questions. Unfortunately, I applied for the internship at the last moment and ended up with the same group. That's why I've mentioned only these five people. Ignored only two of them; the others might be unaware of what is happening.



Obsolete comments, answers in comments, and discussions have been moved to chat. Before posting a comment below this one, please read [this FAQ]nhttps://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4230/7734). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. They may be removed without warning.

My advice is to ignore them and focus on yourself. In my field in the US, the type of person you're describing is not all that uncommon - usually a type-A person with no self-awareness and a willingness to throw others under the bus for a perceived advantaged. In my experience, sooner or later they get found out - others tend to not like them and they eventually rub superiors the wrong way. It doesn't always work out, but 9/10 times, these people start to make more enemies than friends.
In terms of what to do on the day-to-day, remain professional and detached. If they tell you something, verify it for yourself. If they don't tell you something, oh well, you can't rely on them for info. Don't help them or work with them outside of what is required. If they start to do things that actively harm you or are dishonest/unethical - lying, plagiarism, sabotaging experiments, whatever - talk to your supervisor. Most importantly, don't stoop to their level.
And try to surround yourself with people who aren't like that.

I just want compete with myself and stay away from people who invent competition with others out of thin air.

"ignore" is maybe too strong, but "protect yourself, don't be distracted, don't waste emotional energy" is along the same lines.  @sErlSaNo explicitly says to report actively harmful behaviours up the chain.

@Trunk I did not literally mean ignore them. More figuratively - as in don't devote energy or brainspace to worrying about them. BenBolker said it well.

I didn't say to turn the other cheek. I said that these people were not worth engaging with and, if they do escalate, to reach out to a superior who can actually do something. I wanted to give the OP the benefit of the doubt, but we don't really know what is going on. This whole thing could very well be an interpersonal issue on the part of the OP. Plus, they're a student. What type of "showdown" exactly would you recommend? A duel at noon? The best course of action is to worry about themselves and if their classmates do something objectively wrong, to report it to their supervisor.

Let's consider.

There was an internship position for five people, which they secured by approaching the professor before I could...There was one more position available, but they didn't inform me.

Why is it their job to inform you? Why is it their fault if the professor gave the position away before you got around to applying?

They also lie to...ensure they don't complete assignments properly. For example, one of them lied about finishing an assignment, saying he hadn't completed it when he had. He could have said, "I've completed it but can't share it. However, I can help you understand the topic."

How can they "ensure" someone else doesn't complete assignments properly? This is too much. It sounds to me like they told a white lie to avoid being asked to provide tutoring services. While occasionally tutoring your classmates might be a nice thing to do, they are under no obligation to do it, and refusing to do it does not "ensure" that others will fail.

I began distancing myself from them. Realizing this, they flattered the other two batchmates and included them in their team, trying to isolate me further.

You deliberately distanced yourself from them, and now it's their fault that they replaced you? And you assume that they did this to "isolate you", rather than simply to fill the spot?

Unfortunately, I later realized that the other two shared their mindset of ignoring those they don't need. Now, I am without teammates and handling everything alone, which is putting a lot of pressure on me.

So there are 4 other batchmates, and all 4 of them, according to you, are toxic. Hmm. Also, are there no other "batchmates" from other countries who you could work with?

On the first day, their pale faces showed they didn't want me there...These childish, competitive antics are making me feel sick. Sometimes, I wonder if I did something wrong....I'm worried they will plot against me to force me out.

I recommend you stick to actual facts of things they did wrong (e.g., lying), not just your inferences from "their pale faces" or your conclusions about "their childish...antics." If you rewrite your story to contain just the facts without the inferences and conclusions, then you'll find yourself in one of two situations:

There won't be much left. You might not like your coworkers, but they haven't actually done anything wrong. This is then an interpersonal matter rather than an academic one. Or,
There are many facts that didn't make it into the above narrative. In this case, you can use this list of facts to do a much better job telling the story in future (should you ever have to) than you did above. As for next steps, I agree with @sErlSaNo's answer: remain professional but detached, don't rely on them, and talk to your supervisor if they cross the line.


On the contrary, I gave two different interpretations and gave advice for each.

I would suggest that you not extrapolate so much beyond what I wrote. There are certainly situations where I would respond with kindness or anger, but on the internet, I've found it's best to be detached and professional and to focus on next steps rather than assigning blame. In this case, OP is convinced that their labmates have formed a conspiracy against them. I do not believe it would be kind to allow such an extreme assumption to pass unchallenged, though note that I also acknowledged the possibility that the assumption is correct. In any case: I have no more to add, good luck.

This answer would be better if it was gentler and a more charitable interpretation was given to what OP wrote. Probably half the points are to do with OP's non-native / non-standard English, or cultural differences.

They didn’t have to inform me, and neither did I. I didn’t question why they didn’t tell me, but they did ask why I joined at the last moment.
You overextended it. I didn't mean helping with assignments. Living together requires some courtesy. If someone is struggling with a topic and asks for help, saying no despite understanding it is too self-centered. At least honestly say, "I understand, but I can't help right now because I have other tasks." This would have prevented unnecessary toxicity.

Not all of them are toxic. I avoided only two of them but didn't want to make enemies. However, it feels like they are treating me as one.

@user_009 Maybe you are used to a warm, very cosy atmosphere. Not all surroundings are, and between full-on toxicity and cozy familiarity, there is a spectrum. Your situation may be on the cold side, but not yet on full toxicity. Extricate yourself, and your former "fellow students" may not feel they have to actively distance themselves from you. Worry about their machinations after they happen, not before. Sometimes one projects what one fears, causing it to happen in the first place ("self-fulfilling prophesy"). Just treat them as near-strangers in a coffee shop. Courteous but distant.

@user_009 My assumption would be that someone who lies when asked for help is doing so because they want to avoid an argument about it. It seems that they were likely right to expect an argument if your view is that living together comes with an implied promise/obligation of help with coursework.

I would go so far as to say when 4 people are avoiding YOU then you are the toxic one. Always interpreting misfortune as some other person's fault or malice is a telltale sign of a narcissist.

@Stian If someone in a group is being bullied, do you tell the person who is being bullied that it is their fault? We don't know these people and we need to be considerate and moderate.

@Stian Not necessarily. Group dynamics can be nasty. OP might be a very sensitive person, and overly reactive to less sensitive and probably more driven characters. It may be a misunderstanding or they may actively bully OP. Or they consider OP as too strongly attached and do not want to encourage that. We do not know enough. For what I have seen until now, I would probably give OP the benefit of the doubt; but they need to distance themselves from the situation and try to see it as an uninvolved observer if they want to improve it.

Re: "If someone is struggling with a topic and asks for help, saying no despite understanding it is too self-centered." On the contrary; expecting fellow students to help you out of pure courtesy is too self-centered. Your question and such comments do indeed read like it is you who is the 'toxic' one in this dynamic.

@Servaes I think that's a bit too far. The OP simply likes to holds himself to high standards and can is confronted with the reality of an imperfect world that has no interest in doing the same. When I was studying, we largely had a mentality of being in there together, as a team and I'm very glad for that.

@Wouter It's fine to hold yourself to high standards, the problem comes with holding others to that standard and labeling them "toxic" when they don't do things that you've unilaterally decided they are responsible for.

You didn't mention which country you are from. In my country, France, Master's programs are highly competitive and will impact your career and determine your capacity to pursue a PhD program. This kind of behavior is not unknown, and such approaches are as old as the world. Many people here are telling you that you should ignore them, but it is not always possible. One piece of advice: work hard and try your very best. I have a PhD and I worked at Harvard (as a post-doc). My master's degree was one of the most competitive place I have ever been. This can be a shock. My advice is not to let yourself be influenced by people informing you that they did not study or complete their assignments. If you have to work in a group, send emails so that you keep everything in writing. This may help you if things go sour and you need to justify what you have done and what other people have done. As for collaboration, again not sharing your homework in such a competitive place is not a bad idea, all depends on what you want. Because depending on your goal, you may want to be at the very top of your class.

This answer provides useful information, but much of it ("[don't] let yourself be influenced",  the idea of focusing on your own work) is not that different from what others are saying ("Don't help them or work with them outside of what is required")

You misunderstood some aspects. I did not say to share homework. I mentioned not to unnecessarily lie with someone you live in same apartment. Eventually he will figure out and spread animosity. Same happened with the apartment mate and now with me.
What kind of top you are talking about? A lone place where you put anyone under the bus when not required?
I believe most "top things" in the world came out from collaboration not competition

You don't have to put people under the bus to be successful, but some people find it easier that way. What I am saying is that you need to learn to work with all kinds of people. You can only be betrayed by people you trust. What we find acceptable or not is up for debate, from what you describe, I would not like working with them, and I would definitely not trust them.

In addition to the useful answer from @trunk , I suggest that you document all interactions with your colleagues, assuming "colleague" is the right word in this case. A (paper) notebook should be fine: record dates, and don't leave blank paper, so that it is obvious that you aren't inserting stuff later. Stick to objective facts (no "pale faces") and don't leave it behind in the lab.
I also agree with the suggestion of "courteous but distant", and suggest not retaliating to deliberate insults, (but record them). One possible response is: "that is interesting".

@Fe2O3: Probably you mean discreetly.

@Fe2O3 OTOH, it my be more practicable to record interactions discretely, rather then with continuously.
